# Stack layout with transparent composite SWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working on SWT In My requirement I want to show two different forms on same location of composite on the click of button, so I created a Composite with StackLayout. I am able to render both the forms (child composites with different forms) accordingly but the issue is my one form is with orange background and other one is transparent. **When I move from Transparent to Orange composite it works fine. But when I am moving from Orange to Transparent composite the orange composite is still visible in background.** And when I switch to different window and move back to my view it shows only transparent composite that is my requirement. I tries but unable to get only transparent composite instantly on click of button.Below is my code snippet for the same.

```
\\ the container composite with stacklayout.    
bottomComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
        bottomCompositLayOut = new StackLayout();
        bottomComposite.layout(true);

\\first form composite
formComposite = new Composite(bottomComposite, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout formLayout = new GridLayout(3, false);
        formLayout.marginTop = 10;
        formLayout.horizontalSpacing = 20;
        formComposite.setLayout(formLayout);

        formComposite.setBackground(orange);
        GridData formCompositeData = new GridData();
        formCompositeData.widthHint = 800;
        formCompositeData.heightHint = 200;
        formCompositeData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
        formComposite.setLayoutData(formCompositeData);

\\Second transparent composite
progressComposite = new Composite(bottomComposite, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
        GridLayout progressLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        progressLayout.verticalSpacing = 1;
        progressLayout.marginTop = 1;
        progressComposite.setLayout(progressLayout);
        //progressComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        GridData progressCompositeData = new GridData();
        progressCompositeData.widthHint = 800;
        progressCompositeData.heightHint = 200;
        progressCompositeData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
        progressComposite.setLayoutData(progressCompositeData);


//Works properly when I am doing 
bottomComposite.topcontrol = formComposite;

//Shows other form when I made transperent composite to top control.
bottomComposite.topcontrol = progressComposite;
```

Comment: `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND` does **not** mean 'transparent' - the JavaDoc says "This style does not mean "transparent" - widgets that are obscured will not draw through."

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any other way to make the composite transparent. I tried with setBackground(SWT.COLOR_TRANSPARENT) but it doesn't work.

Comment: `setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TRANSPARENT))` is how COLOR_TRANSPARENT is used. See the description [here](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/R4_5/new_and_noteworthy.html) and the linked snippet. I haven't used this and don't know if it will do what you want.

Comment: Tried but not not working :(

Comment: @Shrikant Which version of SWT are you using?